# Checking a monad is idempotent

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories, localization, monads

I have a monad $T: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ on a (Grothendieck) abelian category which preserves filtered colimits and direct sums (but is not exact). There is a finite collection $G$ of compact, projective objects which generate $\mathcal{C}$ in the sense that every object $X$ is presented as a cokernel $R_1 \to R_0\to X\to 0$ of objects $R_1$ and $R_0$ which are (possibly infinite) direct sums of objects in $G$.

I know that $T$ is idempotent on $G$: **Can I conclude that $T$ is idempotent on $\mathcal{C}$**?

If the answer is 'no': what sorts of extra conditions do I need to check? In my case, I have access to the category of algebras for this monad as well, and what I really want to know is that the forgetful functor is fully faithful. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Two very quick reactions; I haven't thought about your question properly yet. (1) If $T$ preserves finite coproducts and filtered colimits, then it preserves infinite coproducts (perhaps you meant infinite coproducts when you said direct sums?). (2) A monad $T$ is idempotent iff the forgetful functor from the category of algebras is fully faithful, so your "really want to know" is already equivalent to the original question.

Comment: Thank you- I was aware of both of these. The reason I mentioned the "really want to know" piece was in case there was a criterion to check that involved knowing something about the category of algebras. Equivalent statements are not always equivalently easy to check :)

Comment: (Tone doesn't parse well on the internet. Sorry if that came across brusque!)

Comment: Nope!  You were totally fine. :-)

Comment: It would help if you add the details of the specific situation where this question arises from.